# CakePHPの設定確認時にトップページが開けない

Tags: cakephp

CakePHPの環境構築をしています。

[CakePHPのダウンロードとインストールの方法](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/26142)

上記のページを参照しながら設定をし、Webサーバの設定で

> `http://[サーバ名]/[プロジェクト名]` にアクセスすると、以下のトップ画面が表示されます。

とありますが、Chromeでこのサイトにアクセスできません。と表示されます。

`http://localhost` でIt works!
`http://localhost/phpinfo.php` でphpinfoページ
が表示されることは確認済み

コマンドで php, apache, composer, cakephp はバージョン確認ができたのでインストールも正常にできていると思われます。

ApacheのhtdocsとCドライブ直下に作成された[プロジェクト]の中身をつなぐためにシンボリックリンクをつけています。

設定ファイル等の編集が必要なのでしょうか。
原因に心当たりがございましたら、ご教授ください。

環境
Windows10
Chrome
PHP 7.4.4
Apache 2.4.43
CakePHP 3.8.10

Comment: プロジェクトディレクトリのパーミッションは、Apacheが参照可能なものでしょうか？出ているエラーが403エラーであればディレクトリのアクセス権の問題である可能性が高いです。

Comment: シンボリックリンクの設定を間違えている可能性があったのでhtdocs直下にプロジェクトを作成しました。同じディレクトリ内のphpinfo.phpは正常に開くので、htdocsまでのディレクトリまでは問題ないはずです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://[サーバ名]/[プロジェクト名]](http://[%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E5%90%8D]/[%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E5%90%8D])
だと開けないので、apacheのhttpd.confにhtdocs/[プロジェクト名]/webroot
までドキュメントルートを指定しました。

[http://[サーバ名]/index.php](http://[%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E5%90%8D]/index.php)
で最初の画面を開きました。